# How to remove date observations that are not exactly 1 year apart

Tags: r

I am working on a database and i have to use only the observations that are exactly 1 year apart from each other. How can i achieve this?

I really don't now how to approach this question...

Comment: Hi Giannis, welcome to stackoverflow. In order to help you, you should provide a reproducible example and/or explain what you have tried already and what did not work. Your problem description is overly broad / unspecific. How does your data look like. Do you have to determine exactly the 1-year-apart for each date-entry, etc. I am not highlighting here that you might want to read up on intervals, durations, etc. when speaking about "dates apart". Below to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

`{lubridate}` is your friend when working with dates (and `{tidyverse}`). I highlighted already that your problem is not well defined. To get you started the following might help.

```
library(dplyr)      # for tabular data crunching
library(lubridate)  # date/time processing helper functions

#------- let's define some start and end dates to "compare" ------
start_dates <- ymd("2021-11-01", "2020-11-01", "2021-10-31")
end_dates   <- ymd("2022-11-01", "2021-11-01", "2022-10-07")

#------- we plug them into a data frame, i.e columns
# and add one year to the start date lubridate::years(1) and 
# compare this to the given end date
my_dates <- data.frame(start = start_dates, end = end_dates) %>% 
  mutate(apart_one_year = start + years(1) == end)

my_dates
```

This yields:

```
        start        end apart_one_year
1 2021-11-01 2022-11-01           TRUE
2 2020-11-01 2021-11-01           TRUE
3 2021-10-31 2022-10-07          FALSE
```

You can now filter for the TRUE condition and process your data further.

Comment: Yes, you are right, my post was broad. I need to clean data gathered from 6k companies, in order to do some checks on them. My issue is how to identify if one company has different lengths of fiscal years( for example, one year ending in June and the other in March). I have tried to filter, and now im trying to figure out if lubridate can work for me, but im a newb at R...

Comment: No prob with that. We stand on the shoulders of giants. It is good to see that newbies join the league :). If your data is sort of: `firm n; start_date_of_fiscal_year; end_date_of_fiscal_year`, you can work with what I proposed above. I would assume start and end dates (of operations) might be also under 1 year. Thus, you may want to check for the number of dates between first and last operation, etc. For this you could use baseR's `difftime(end_date, start_date, units = "days") or {lubridate} and then create a check on the calculated difference of days (e.g. shorter than 365 or 366 days).